# Link does not change color when on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery function that will change color when link is clicked. My code will select the parent of the clicked element and add a new class called "active" and remove all class "active" in siblings that has active class too. But when I execute my code, it doesn't make a change at all. Also checked the console, the active does not add to the clicked li.

Here is my code:

```js
$("#menu-links > li a").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu-links > li a").parent().addClass('.active').siblings().removeClass('.active')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-links">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try using `addClass("active")` and `removeClass('active')` without the **dot**

Comment: Are you creating `menu-links` before or after your code runs?  You might need event delegation.

Comment: after the code runs..@freedomn-m

Answer (score 2):

you should use `this` and remove the dot from class name in add/remove functions:

```js
$("#menu-links > li a").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-links">
  <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">PROFILE</a></li>
  <li> <a href="#">CONTACTS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you're using snippets, make sure they are runable, they're not just for code output.  (in this case missing jquery)

Comment: tried this but still didn't work. by the way, I'm using gulp.js though. does it affect?

Comment: in my project, I used jquery-3.4.1

Comment: I'm not sure about gulp. it depends on your config, but normally it shouldn't. Re-check your code, maybe you missed something. See the example above.

Comment: This answer was based on all the information provided in the question and the snippet above shows that this works in this scenario.  If it doesn't work for you, please a) add *all* required information to the question b) explain *why it doesn't work for you* - ie what does/doesn't it do.  Does it work for you in the answer?  But not your code?  What's different in your code?   Did you run it in doc ready `$(function() { ...` - *"didn't work" is not enough information*

Comment: it didnt work just what I expected. The active li must be changed to the clicked li but it did not work. I don't know why. There are no errors in my console as I inspected it.

Comment: Well, that's a start :)  What do you get with `console.log($("#menu-links > li a").length)` if you add that just before the click handler code.  Add a console.log or `debugger;` statement *inside* the event handler - does that get hit?

Comment: Re-check your code: a) Did you put `$(this)`? b) did you removed the dot from class names?

Answer (score 0):

Try using like this

```
$("#menu-links > li").on("click",'a', function() {
    $("#menu-links > li a").parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

(or)

```
$("document").on("click","#menu-links li a" function() {
    $("#menu-links > li a").parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

The problem might be due to your javascript loads before the creation of #menu-links list. The second snippet will work if this is a problem.

Comment: this code will add active class on all `<li>` elements, not only clicked one.

Comment: I see now my problem. I am using gulp and I noticed that my minified js files did not make any change. I edited and edited the code but it doesn't make any change in my minified js file.

Comment: @AlexDeneris Maybe you forgot to run gulp watcher task.